# Error when using the polar function in Octave: Too many inputs

Tags: octave, octave-gui

When I try to plot using polar, the following error is returned:

```matlab
polar (0:0.1:10*pi, 0:0.1:10*pi);
```

```
error: line: function called with too many inputs
error: called from
    line
    polar>__update_polar_grid__ at line 368 column 3
    polar at line 128 column 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might have created another function `polar` that shadows (hides) the built-in one. `which polar` will tell you which function you’re actually calling.

Comment: Actually, looking at your error message, it might be the `line` function that you shadowed, causing the call to `line` within `polar` to fail.

Comment: I found the error - it was in the line function as you pointed out. I had an old function with the name "line" that was overwriting Octave's built-in function. When I deleted it, the error was resolved. Thank you for the help!